# PHP : preg_replace() with foreign characters not working correctly

Tags: php, character-encoding, preg-replace

I have an array of strings in Korean similar to `사람 [saram]` where they all consist of the Hangeul(Korean alphabet) and then the English pronunciation in brackets.

The preg_replace I have is:

```
preg_replace("/\[.*\]/u","","사람 [saram]");
```

But the output is always:

```
ì‚¬ëžŒ
```

or some similar gibberish.

I'm 90% sure it's the Korean characters because when I try:

```
preg_replace("/\[.*\]/u","","Person [saram]");
```

Only `Person` is outputted. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What encoding is the PHP file in and what encoding are you using for the web page?

Comment: have your try mbstring http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php

Comment: I'm pretty new to regex and encoding in php, I have the HTML set to charset='UTF-8' How do I check the php encoding?